# How to handle time consuming webservice operation through Javascipt Callbacks

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have the following operation to so in one of my Web applications. I have a function that returns a value. This value should be passed to a web service method that runs **separately** to my web application. This web service operation takes some time to complete, so this has to be run in the background and should return a message once it is completed. I wanted to do this through Javascript callbacks. The basic flow of the code is as follows;

```
 Dim shr_intfB_Common_LCI As clsCreamsCommon
 Dim stringResult As StringResult
 shr_intfB_Common_LCI = New clsCreamsCommon
 Call shr_intfB_Common_LCI.CreamsBooking(clsTapsCreamsPropsDtl,
                               intRetCode, strMessage, intRequestId
                               )

// This intRequestId needs to be passed to the following web service.
Do
   Threading.Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000) '10 Second
   stringResult = objService.CheckRequestStatus(objServiceUser, intRequestId)
   Loop Until stringResult Is Nothing Or stringResult.ReturnCode <> 2    

//The stringResult includes the followings which I have to display. 
MessageBox(Me, stringResult.ReturnCode, stringResult.ReturnData + stringResult.ReturnMessage)
```

I want to do this without using Threads or Task since this is a web application, but using JavaScript callbacks. Please help out me on this.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a call back function in JavaScript you can use jQuery ajax or PageMethods call

Both option will run separately, once the web method complete execution, will return,either success or failure call back

PageMethods in JavaScript

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/631342/Calling-csharp-function-in-javascript